# KTable not triggered

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm facing an issue with KTable , i cannot make it work on my project, i will share a simple example with spring boot and kafka to read a KTable and then display values.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class FocusDataLoadStream {
    private final StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder;
    @PostConstruct
    public void replicationStream() {
        KTable<Object, Object> actors = streamsBuilder.stream("actor").selectKey((key, value) -> {
            try {
                return new ObjectMapper().readValue(((String) value).substring(6, ((String) value).length() - 1), Actor.class).getPosId();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return key;
        }).groupByKey().reduce((agg, newValue) -> newValue);
        actors.toStream().foreach((key,value) -> System.out.println(value));
    }
}
```

So here i have a topic called actor , and data look like json but some extra wrong values , that's why i'm doing the object mapper with the substring (test only), and at the end i just want to read the stream again , but its never called , but when i create a stream directly its working

data looks like :{"id":"100","posId":"100","name":"name"}

if you can please help me with that , i'm blocked since yesterday

thanks

Comment: What do you mean "but it's never called"? Which function is not called?

Comment: the foreach method

Comment: By default, `KTables` use a cache to reduce the downstream output rate. Try to set the cache size to zero to get immediate output: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html